# Set the background color of the parentNode associated with an input box's value being null

Tags: javascript

Here is my code. When the button is clicked and the value of "requiredTitleValue" is null. The background color of the parent node associated with the  tag should be set to "red". The problem is that the new backgroundColor is not sticking after the button click.

backgroundColor should stick after submit button is clicked and "requiredTitleValue" is null but it is not.

```
var checkTitleValue = function(){
    var requiredTitleObject = document.getElementById("requiredTitle");
    var requiredTitleValue = requiredTitleObject.nodeValue;

    if(requiredTitleValue == null){
        alert("Object is null");
        requiredTitleObject.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        requiredTitleObject.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
} 

function formValidator(){
    checkTitleValue();
}
```

Comment: This is... weird? You're using `.nodeValue` instead of `.textContent`, you're using `==` instead of `===`, you're checking against `null` instead of letting JS coerce the value to a boolean, you're using `alert` instead of `console.warn`, you're directly setting `style` instead of adding a class using the `.classList` functions, and all the code inside that anonymous function bound to the `var checkTitleValue` should just be in your `formValidator` function, that var is entirely unnecessary. This is just bad JS and JS practices =/

Answer (score 0):

As per @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans, this code needs some serious help.
Using better practices will a make your code cleaner and easier to read, and b prevent and fix the bugs you are experiencing.

Some fast thoughts:

- Don't use var. Period. Always use `let` and `const` to prevent weird hoisting behaviors
- Use classes in place of style to toggle styles on elements. It's far cleaner and easier to modify down the road
- Use classList to modify the classes. Note how I'm able to add / remove the class in one line, rather than having if else everywhere
- Contain your code. Only allow code to exist where it needs to. Only your validator needs the checkTitleValue Function, so define it there

```js
function formValidator(){
    // Notice this is const to prevent a redefinition of the lambda
    const checkTitleValue = () => {
      const requiredTitleInput = document.getElementById("requiredTitle");
      const requiredTitleValue = requiredTitleInput;
      requiredTitleInput.classList.toggle('input-error', !!requiredTitleValue);
      requiredTitleInput.parentNode.classList.toggle('input-error', !! requiredTitleValue);
    }
    checkTitleValue();
}
```

Comment: I agree. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Shouldn't "const requiredTitleValue = requiredTitleObject.value;"  instead be "const requiredTitleValue = requiredTitleInput.value"

Comment: You never got the requiredTitleObject.

Comment: Updated to have the correct value. Hopefully it was clear enough for ya though.